# Unable to transfer files (put) using ftp or filezilla from windows to ubuntu VM

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, ftp, vsftpd, filezilla

I've setup a ubuntu 64 bit VM (16.04) using Oracle VirtualBox. Using ftp, I am able to connect to the VM. I am also able to list (ls) the contents of the folder. However I am unable to put files to the VM.

```
C:\>ftp x.x.x.x
Connected to x.x.x.x.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
200 Always in UTF8 mode.
User (x.x.x.x:(none)): user
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
ftp> quote pasv
227 Entering Passive Mode (...)
ftp> put trnsfr.txt
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
550 Permission denied.
```

On ubuntu, I set permissions on folder to rwx on owner,group,all. I then modified /etc/vsftpd.conf as follows:

```
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=30000
pasv_max_port=30100
port_enable=yes
pasv_address=x.x.x.x
```

allowed data connections and restarted vsftpd daemon:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --destination-address 30000:30100 -j ACCEPT
/etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
```

but still permission error exists.

I then tried using filezilla: The connections is successful but again files can not be transferred: with dft settings in vsftpd:

```
Response:   550 Permission denied.
Error:     Critical file transfer error
```

with the settings in vsftpd.conf as above: the following is displayed in filezilla:

```
Error:  The data connection could not be established: WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL -     Cannot assign requested address
```

I believe the problem is to do with the data connection - but am not sure what/how to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `write_enable=yes` in `vsftpd.conf`? The default is `no`.

Change that and try again. I think the other error is just a result of that.